# SQL-Joins and SubQueries-Explanation Please

Tags: sql

Joins can be always expressed as subqueries, and vice versa may not be possible. As joins are symmetric. Can anyone provide me an example for this statement.

As I am unable to get it fully.

Comment: I know this question has been asked before (and scored highly if I recall) but I cannot locate it. Perhaps someone else can?

Comment: Where does this statement come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the first statement is true anyway.

For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
INNER JOIN y
    ON 1 = 1;
```

How does one express the nature of a cross join using x and a subquery based on y?

Or even a triangular join:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
INNER JOIN y
    ON y.val < x.val;
```

So the first statement must be restricted to cases where there are at most one rows joining so that you can use a scalar subquery?